# UserControl in repeater - Child DataBind() being called before repeater OnItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, page-lifecycle, webusercontrol

I am attempting to databind a user control (B) inside a repeater (R) that is itself contained within a user control (A).

Page calls A.DataBind
A.OnInit attaches a method to R.OnItemDataBound
A.DataBind sets R.DataSource and calls R.DataBind
B.DataBind is called **BEFORE** R.OnItemDataBound fires.

This is a problem - because I am setting B.DataSourceProperties and calling B.DataBind from R.OnItemDataBound's attached method. (Like I do whenever I nest repeaters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your code from the repeater's `ItemDataBound` handler to its `ItemCreated` handler. I had the same problem and moving my code from `ItemDataBound` to `ItemCreated` resolved it.